# Microsoft azure service bus topic Complete() Method is missing in Message class in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Am using ServiceBusTrigger function to read events from Servicebus topic. (Asp.net core 3.1 )

I have an usecase, whenever there is failure in code, I want to **Abandon** the message, and when success I will **complete** the message.

In the current namespace **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** we have **Message** Class, but this class doesn't have **Complete(),abandon()** methods.

Do we have any option to satisfy my requirement with ServiceBusTrigger function?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute, within that the function runtime takes care of `abandoning` or `completing` the message using `PeekLock` behaviour.

This behaviour is default to the runtime while receiving messages. It calls `Complete` on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls `Abandon` if the function fails.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior) is the Microsoft's documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Messages can be received from a queue or a subscription, not a topic. You'd be using `QueueClient` or a `SubscriptionClient`. Optionally, a `MessageReceiver` can be used as well. All the disposition methods are on the receiving clients.